# Is there a function/package/whatever in Python that can average y values based on intervals of x?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series

I have some brain size data of homo sapiens that ranges from 300k-100 years ago. Each specimen has it's its brain size measured in cubic centimeters and a corresponding date. I want to do some change-point analysis on my sample, but the problem is the data isn't distributed appropriately, with over 50% of the data being from the past 100 years. To remedy this, I want to find the average brain size over 100-year intervals and plot the data accordingly.

Technically, I could do this by hand, but in the future, if I want to increase the size of my data set, this may become harder and harder to do, so I was wondering if there is some function/method/package that could make this process simpler?

Comment: `sort` by year, `itertools.groupby` century, and `statistics.mean` the sizes in each group.  Should be a one-liner.

Comment: One can certainly group the data as suggested, but I have to wonder what, exactly, you are getting when you group by 100 year bins on a data set which is very sparsely scattered over 300,000 years ... It seems like geographical variation and genetic drift are going to be confounding factors which are unaccounted, and which can show up as temporal variations (e.g. geographic group 1 is represented at 200 ka, group 2 is represented at 100 ka, and they're different -- it looks like a temporal change but it's not).

Comment: It's easy to solve the computational problems here, much more challenging to sort out the non-computational stuff.

Comment: @Robert Dodier 

Well, the point of grouping the data by 100-year intervals is to reduce heteroscedasticity. I'm also cutting down the sample size and performing normality tests until I reach a homoscedastic and normally distributed sample. You bring up a good point about geographic variation being a possible confounding factor, and I have actually gone through my dataset and written down the location. Eventually, I'll update my code to account for this. Admittedly, I am still very new to python and statistical analysis, so I'm still trying to figure everything out.

Answer (score 2):

Bucketize your years as you see fit and then groupby and average:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
    yearBucket  size
0            1     4
1            1     7
2            2     4
3            2     4
4            3     2
5            3     2
6            4     0
7            4     5
8            5     3
9            5     5
10           6     9
11           6     5
12           6     6
13           6     3
14           6     0
15           6     4
16           6     8
17           6     9
18           6     7
19           6     6
20           6     7
21           6     8

In [39]: df.groupby('yearBucket').agg('mean')
Out[39]:
            size
yearBucket
1            5.5
2            4.0
3            2.0
4            2.5
5            4.0
6            6.0
```